# Blazor and EventCallback, both update data and run code in parent component?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, parent-child

I have a parent and a child component in Blazor. Is there an easier way to both bind-Value between parent-child and also run code in parent if bind-value changed?

I have this code

Parent:

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<Test @bind-BitValue="MyValue" BitValueChangedCallback="HandleMyValueChanged"/>

Welcome to your new app.

<br />
MyValue : <span>@MyValue</span> <br />
MyTValue : <span>@MyTValue</span>


@code {
    public int MyValue { get; set; }

    public int MyTValue { get; set; } = 0;

    private void HandleMyValueChanged (int newValue)
    {
        MyTValue = newValue * 2;

    }
}
```

And Child "Test.razor" :

```
<h3>Test</h3>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>


@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int BitValue { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<int> BitValueChanged { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<int> BitValueChangedCallback { get; set; }

    private async Task IncrementCount()
    {
        BitValue++;
        await BitValueChanged.InvokeAsync(BitValue);
        await BitValueChangedCallback.InvokeAsync(BitValue);
    }
}
```

As you can see I have 2 InvokeAsync in child, one that are linked to Value and one that trigger a method in parent.  Are there a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try use `@bind-BitValue:after` to bind event to a method:

```
<h3>Test</h3>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int BitValue { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<int> BitValueChanged { get; set; }

    private async Task IncrementCount()
    {
        BitValue++;
        await BitValueChanged.InvokeAsync(BitValue); 
    }
}
```

```
@page "/"
<Test @bind-BitValue="MyValue" @bind-BitValue:after="()=>HandleMyValueChanged(MyValue)" />
<br />
MyValue : <span>@MyValue</span>
<br />
MyTValue : <span>@MyTValue</span>


@code {
    public int MyValue { get; set; }

    public int MyTValue { get; set; } = 0;

    private void HandleMyValueChanged(int newValue)
    {
        MyTValue = newValue * 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: That one works!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`@bind-{PropertyName}` is short-hand for setting a one-way binding and a (generated) callback.

Instead of using an second callback, you can just drop the `@bind-` notation:

```
<Test BitValue="MyValue" BitValueChanged="HandleMyValueChanged"/>
```

This works for all parameters with two-way binding, ie InputText.Value .

And to follow the guidelines about not changing your parameters from inside:

```
private async Task IncrementCount()
{
 //   BitValue++;  -- would make it different from the parent value 
    await BitValueChanged.InvokeAsync(BitValue+1);  // parent will set our BitValue
 //   await BitValueChangedCallback.InvokeAsync(BitValue); -- no longer needed
}
```

The component will receive the new value BitValue+1 from its parent through the normal life-cycle and can (should) react to that in a standard way.

Comment: Of course, I have used this method many times before, long time before I begin to use @bind- . DOH thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While @QiangFu's answer works, there's a couple minor issues.

```cs
 BitValue++;
```

Mutating a `Parameter` within a component is bad practice.  While it has no side effects here, any mutation applied within the component will be overwritten when the component is updated by it's parent.

`BitValue` will be set to the value you pass back through the EventCallback as part of the parent render process.

Modified Test:

```cs
<h3>Test</h3>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>
@code {
    [Parameter] public int BitValue { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public EventCallback<int> BitValueChanged { get; set; }

    private Task IncrementCount()
    {
        return BitValueChanged.InvokeAsync(this.BitValue + 1);
    }
}
```

In Home you don't need to do this `@bind-BitValue:after="()=>HandleMyValueChanged(MyValue)"`.  `BitValue` has already been set by the bind setter before `after` is called.

```cs
@page "/"

<Test @bind-BitValue="this.MyValue" @bind-BitValue:after="HandleMyValueChanged" />

<div class="m-2 p-2">
    <br />
    MyValue : <span>@MyValue</span>
    <br />
    MyTValue : <span>@MyTValue</span>
</div>


@code {
    // Do these need to be public?
    private int MyValue;

    private int MyTValue;

    private void HandleMyValueChanged()
    {
        MyTValue = this.MyValue * 2;
    }
}
```